# Premiere Pro on Windows 10 N version - Can't import MP4

Tags: premiere, video-editor, mp4, windows

I've tried to install various codecs - not working.

I still can download whole Media Feature, but that's what I would like to avoid, since N version is way lightier.

Can you please advice me how I can import MP4 files into Adobe Premiere Pro on Windows 10 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

my dear friend
Windows alone is not enough, you need such peripherals
Use the K-Lite Codec Pack. After installing this item, you should not have any problems

The function of this package is to be able to run relevant codecs such as mp4 in Premier Pro

Good luck.